Is an ablative/buoyant “lander” a reasonable design for a Jupiter probe?
It is difficult to design a “lander” for a Jupiter mission for several reasons:

There is no “land” to “land on” since Jupiter’s atmosphere just gets
denser towards the planetary center.
There is a literally astronomic amount of kinetic energy to be shed
as the descent vehicle arrives from orbit.

One possible design is to make the vehicle almost entirely from ablative heat shield material. The vehicle’s surface would ablate as it descended, until enough speed was lost that its trajectory became ballistic. At that point, it would fall until the ambient atmospheric density matched its own density. Once densities matched, the vehicle would be, in effect, a balloon tracking the isopycnal (constant density) contour.
The density of Carbon phenolic heat shield material  is 1.31 - 1.55 g/cc
https://www.matweb.com/search/datasheet.aspx?matguid=bdd98b907c6f4695b6578b12efbd1321
The Galileo probe survived to a pressure of 22 bar (depth of about 132 km below cloud tops). Its data indicated  a density of 1.5 g/cc at depths of 50-100km below cloud top.  I could not locate the primary source of this density data. ChatGPT  provided the depth/density estimate, and Wikipedia provided the pressure/temperature data below.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Structure_of_Jovian_atmosphere.png
From this information, it would seem that a mass of carbon phenolic composite, enclosing an instrument package, which entered the Jovian atmosphere would arrive at buoyant equilibrium at the depth of the middle of the cloud layer. This would be a good location for a weather report.
Is a buoyant/ablative “lander” a reasonable design for a Jupiter probe?

I haven't tried to get through to the full text, but this paper seems to tread at least some of the same ground https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7943618

another potential difficulty: How deep could a gas giant communications network penetrate?

@uhoh ... Good point. No purpose is served by a probe that can't talk to you. Your reference implied radio communication may work, at least at low data rates, down to 100bar level, which is well below the cloud level shown in the Wikipedia graph.

@ErinAnne … dang paywalls !!!   Aerostatic (“lighter than air”) craft are, by definition, lighter than air. This means they must operate in portions of the atmosphere of approximately their own density. “Balloons” would operate high above the Jovian cloud layer. The craft proposed in the OP is greater density than water and so would operate inside the cloud layer, collecting a different data set. The gliders mentioned in your link would presumably be similar to oceanographic gliders and therefore also work in high density portions of the Jovian atmosphere.

What does a "literally astronomic amount" mean?  Aren't all amounts in outer space "literally astronomic"?

@Woody "aerostatic" seems to mean motionless with respect to the surrounding air. The easiest way to do that is of course have neutral buoyancy and no other propulsive forces, but a solar/battery powered helicopter could also remain aerostatic I suppose, as could more creative/clever strategies, such as a modified version of this. Also, neutral buoyancy means it has the same average density as the local air; it's not "lighter" than it.

One big question would be just how hot the inner workings would get during all that ablation. Perhaps manageable with the right layering.

@uhoh ... "lighter than air" is an example of folk etymology, also known as a "fossilized error". That's why I put it in quotes. Thanks for the link to DAP, a very interesting concept to me, as a sailor. Jupiter's turbulent atmosphere would make it a challenge, but what a ride !!! As well, it would provide electrical generation as a substitute for solar.

@gerrit ... You are right. It was meant as a pun,

@JonCuster ya it has to be lighter than air in the beginning, otherwise it just sits/hovers there near the ground. :-)
